# Пустой обозреватель решения ASP NET Core MVC, проблема с Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

установил Visual Studio 2022, создаю проект ASP NET (модель-представление-контроллер), а файлы в самом Visual Studio 2022 не появляются, Visual Studio я почти не трогал и не настраивал (только установил разширение Material Theme), открыл папку с проектом, а там все файлы которые должны быть. имя пользователя - на английском. Пробовал открыть site1.sln - ничего не меняется.

**UPD: 14.12.2022:**
Попробовал переустановить Visual Studio 2022, не помогло, подозрения падают на самих микрософтов, драйвера .NET Frameworks на месте, jdk 11 версии от самих майкрософтов тоже установлено(хотя на пк установлена и 19 и 16)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: при установке необходимо отметить нужные фичи
возможно что-то забыли отметить, поэтому студия себя так ведет

Comment: @Lenz, установил почти все дополнения для веб-разработки (кроме тех, которые предназначены для командной разработки), даже пробовал с разными версиями .NET фреймворка, всё также.
А у вас какая версия Visual Studio?

Comment: надо пробовать доставлять компоненты системы, видимо чего то нет
в крайнем случае переставить ось (Windows 10/11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема устранилась путём регрейда ***Visual Studio 2022** >> **Visual Studio  2019***

Comment: это очень странно, 22я работает без проблем

Comment: @Lenz я переустановил Windows 10 для теста, сразу же скачал Visual Studio 2022, проблема осталась, удалил 2022 версию, скачал 2019 - проблема решилась. Как это работает я незнаю

Comment: может проблема в железе?
стоит отправить майкам конфигурацию вашей системы и железа и Ось
пусть разбираются - это их работа

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что в системной переменной PATH строка

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\
```

оказывается выше в списке строки

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\
```

И система не видит пакет SDK, который установлен в C:\Program Files. Нужно поменять их местами или сдвинуть строку х86 в конец списка. Проверить правильность можно, если набрать в командной строке

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

Comment: а можно подробней как это сделать?